# Detect if UIViewController is running inside an existing UINavigationController

Tags: ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm creating a generic reusable UIViewController component that people can add to their applications. It requires a navigation bar at the top where it will add some buttons.

I can easily create a navigationBar and add the buttons, but if the developer using my component is adding the view as part of an existing navigation structure, they might end up with 2 navigation bars.

In other words, if my view is loaded with:

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

then it should not add a navigationbar and use what's already there. If the view is loaded with:

```
 [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

then it should add its own navbar.

Without requiring the developer that uses my controller to do something like a useNavBar:YES, is there a way to do this automatically?

Something like a [self isRunningInsideANavigationController] or [self hasNavigationBar] would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `self.navigationController` for that purpose. It will return nil or the navigationController.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure that would be a reliable way. But luckily it's that simple :)